# javascript - iterate through all instances of an object

Tags: javascript

In order to process lyrics to an album, I have made a `constructor`:

```
var Song = function(side, name, index, duration, author, lyrics) {
    this.side = side;
    this.name = name;
    this.index = index;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.author = author;
    this.lyrics = lyrics;
    globalLyrics.push(this.name, this.lyrics);
    };
```

I also created a global variable to keep track of the lyrics:

```
    var globalLyrics = [];
```

Then I created, say, 24 instances to Song:

```
   var song1 = new Song('Mithras', 'Wicked', 1, '3:45', 'Me and The Plant', 
           ["politicians", "politician", "politics", "telling", 
           "lies", "lie", "to", "media", "the", "youngsters", 
           "young", "elders", "time", "that", "passes", "pass", "by", 
           "oh", "no", "lie", "detector", "detection", "souls", "as", 
           "far", "illusion", "goes", "all", "sinners", "sin", "around", 
           "sun", "earth", "atom", "atoms", "mind", "angels", "angel", 
           "prophet", "prophets", "martyr", "knives", "elder", "detect", 
           "shit", "flies", "fly", "meat", "is", "knife", "and", "death", 
           "life", "I", "am", "gonna", "going", "cast", "a", "sacred", 
           "circle"]);

           (...)//all the way to:

var song24 = new Song('Lab', 'Buffalo', 23, '3:10', 'Me and The Plant', 
        ["this", "tambourine", "is", "waging", "a", "war", "will",
        "drecnched", "in", "blood", "flood", "egg", "shape",
        "shaped", "rock", "rocking", "to", "kill", "the", "bull",
        "slay", "slain", "by", "dogs", "snakes", "raven", "scorpio",
        "lion", "headed", "head", "god", "rise"]);
```

Given an input from the client, such as:

```
   var input = ["this", "tambourine", "is"];
```

I made a method as to count intersections between the input with lyrics' words:

```
Song.prototype.countIntersect = function(input) {

var lyrics = this.lyrics;
var count = 0;
var temp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    for(var k = 0; k < lyrics.length; k++){
        if(input[i] == lyrics[k]){
            count += 1;
            temp.push(input[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

}

QUESTION:

I want to create a `function` able to iterate through ALL Song `instances`, returning the name of the song that has the most words `intersections` with the `input`.

Do I have to make a tracker with `intersection` `counts` for all `instances` of `this.lyrics`, and then return the song corresponding to the largest `count`?

DESIRED ANSWER: Given the `input` example, after creating this new `prototype` `function`, I would like to have it iterating through all lyrics and returning //'Buffalo', the name of the song24.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in var) {
    // this will skip native keys and only alert user assigned keys
    if (!var.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    alert(key + ':' + var[key]);
}
```

here is a fiddle showing the details relative to your usage: http://jsfiddle.net/aequalsb/xh1t8d9p/